# How to show through which cassandra node your request was served

Tags: spring-boot, docker, cassandra

**Why?**

For educational purposes. I think it would be really nice for my audience to actually "see" it work like that.

**Setup**

- A dockerized Spring boot REST API (serving up customer information)
- A dockerized Cassandra cluster consisting of three connected nodes, holding customer data with a replication factor of two.

**Suggestions**

- Showing which IP address or container name served my request
- Showing which IP address or container name held the data that was used to show my request.
- If I were to run these nodes on three seperate physical machines, maybe which machine held my data?
- Something else you have in mind that really shows the distributed capabilities of Cassandra

Can this be achieved in docker logs or something in Spring data Cassandra that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Spring Data, but in normal Java driver you can get execution information from `ResultSet` via `getExecutionInfo`, and call function `getQueriedHost` from it.  If you're using default DCAware/TokenAware load balancing policy, then you reach at least one of the nodes that hold your data. The rest of information you can get via `Metadata` class from which you can get a list of token ranges owned by hosts, generate a token for your partition key, and lookup in the token ranges.

P.S. See [Java driver documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.6/) for more details.

Comment: I'm afraid my knowledge of Java is to limited. Can you expand on how I can get reach Resultset and Metadata from say a spring boot REST controller?

Comment: I’m not really familiar with spring. For driver side - just follow documentation that i referenced